# Kloosterman's famous paper $ax^2+by^2+cz^2+dt^2$ 's Lemma 2

Tags: number-theory

I'm reading Kloosterman's paper *On the representation of numbers in the form $ax^2+by^2+cz^2+dt^2$*. In his proof of Lemma 2, he writes:
$$
S_{sP,q,v_j} = \exp\frac{2\pi i P''v_s}{q} \, S_{sP,q} 
= \frac{1}{2} \exp\frac{2\pi i P'' v_s}{q} \, S_{sP,4q}
$$
however, if we need this to be true, we'll have to show
$$
S_{sP,q} = \frac{1}{2} S_{sP,4q}
$$
but this isn't generally true. What if, for example, $P=1,s=4,q=2$?

I've finished reading the whole paper, and I found some small flaws, all except this one, I am able to correct them on my own. However, I can't correct this one. And it seems to me that the whole paper is relied on this fact, so I'm really confused. Help me guys!

Here,
$$
S_{p,q,v} 
= \sum_{j=0}^{q-1} 
\exp\biggl(\frac{2p \pi i j^2}{q} + \frac{2v\pi i j}{q}\biggr).
$$

Comment: Kloosterman  had also a paper with the same title in Proceedings of the London M. Soc. I have the Acta  Mathematica paper, same year,  about 58 pages.

Comment: I've solved this problem! lemma 2 is indeed wrong; but we can directly prove lemma 3 from lemma 1: notice that  lemma 2 only goes wrong when some $q_s \equiv 2\pmod{4}$, then we choose $\Lambda=8G$, where $G$ is chosen as in the original paper. Then we can still prove the product has a period of $\Lambda$.